# Running multiple commands simultaneously from python

Tags: python

I want to run three commands at the same time from python. The command format is query.pl -args

Currently I am doing

```
os.system("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server1' >> log1.txt")

os.system("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server2' >> log2.txt")

os.system("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server3' >> log3.txt")
```

I want to query all three servers at the same time but in this case, each command executes only after the last one has finished. How can I make them simultaneous? I was thinking of using '&' at the end but I want the next part of the code to be run only when all three command finish

Comment: Have you read up on the `subprocess` module yet?  What specific questions did you have?  This is a duplicate of dozens of `subprocess` related questions.  You might want to look at those and list what is unique or different about your question.

Comment: That, and are you aware of the fact that you are, probably calling _perl_ scripts from python? Do you want our universe to implode then?

Comment: Why does the question title say "two" but the question says "three" and shows 3?  Why the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module and have all three running independently: use subprocess.Popen.  Take care in setting the "shell" parameter correctly.

Use the wait() or poll() method to determine when the subprocesses are finished.

Comment: but How will I know when all three have finished? I want the rest of the code to execute only when the commands finish running

Comment: @Jaelebi:  `status = [ p.wait() for p in list_of_popen_objects ]` usually works to see if all processes are done.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server1' &") 
os.system("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server2' &") 
os.system("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server3' &")
```

in this case - process will be started in background

Comment: "&" - this symbol at the end of shell command - says that it must work in background. That's why all process will be run together

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)

```
tasks = ("query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server1'",\
"query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server2'",\
"query.pl -results '10000' -serverName 'server1'")

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        os.system(item)

q = Queue()
for i in tasks:
     t = Thread(target=worker)
     t.setDaemon(True)
     t.start()

for item in tasks:
    q.put(item)

q.join()
```

Comment: Using threads in this way isn't really a good idea when clean and predictable asynchronous IO facilities are available. Additionally, spawning processes and threads don't mix well on some platforms.